# Reading two catalogs with opendir in C (linux)

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to write a daemon which will copy the contents of one catalog to another. Both catalog paths are given as arguments to the main function. I'm writing the file names to a 2d array (let's say two buffers of equal lengths) by using opendir. Now the issue I encountered, is that no matter in what order, or which catalogs are loaded, the first buffer is always overwritten by a part of the filenames from the second buffer, double dot and other random stuff. The second buffer always contains what it's supposed to, while the first refuses to work. It can't be the files or rights, because if I flip the order of catalogs, the second buffer is still correct, while the first is not. I'm guessing I'm missing something trivial, I'm a newbie when it comes to C, sorry for the inconvienience. Here is the function used to save file names from a catalog to the buffer.

```
    void cat_read (char* cat, int buf)
    {
        DIR *dir_cat;
        struct dirent *ent_cat;
        int i = 0;
        if ((dir_cat = opendir (cat)) != NULL) {
            while ((ent_cat = readdir (dir_cat)) != NULL) {

                if (ent_cat->d_type == DT_REG)
                {
                    buffer_cat[i][buf] = ent_cat->d_name;
                    printf("%i writing to buffer number %i file %s \n",i, buf, ent_cat->d_name);
                    i++;
                }
            }

            closedir (dir_cat);
       } else {
             /* could not open directory */
             printf ("opening directory went wrong \n");

         }
    }
```

Here is the main function

```
    int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
    {
        cat_read(argv[1], 0);
        cat_read(argv[2], 1);
        int ix=0;
        for(ix=0;ix<10;ix++)
            printf("%i buffer1: %s buffer2: %s \n", ix, buffer_cat[ix][0], buffer_cat[ix][1]);
    }
```

And here is the terminal output:

```
    0 writing to buffer number 0 file 2.txt 
    1 writing to buffer number 0 file 234.txt 
    2 writing to buffer number 0 file 23.txt 
    3 writing to buffer number 0 file 1.txt 
    0 writing to buffer number 1 file tet12.txt 
    1 writing to buffer number 1 file tet1.txt 
    2 writing to buffer number 1 file tet123.txt 
    0 buffer1: tet12.txt buffer2: tet12.txt 
    1 buffer1: tet1.txt buffer2: tet1.txt 
    2 buffer1: .. buffer2: tet123.txt 
    3 buffer1: xt buffer2: (null) 
    4 buffer1: (null) buffer2: (null) 
    5 buffer1: (null) buffer2: (null)
```

Comment: What is buffer_cat?  There's no definition here.

Comment: Ah sorry - char* buffer_cat[100][2]

Comment: The dirent structure returned is not guaranteed to live beyond one call to readdir, so you would need to copy it if you want to keep it around.  You can't just point to the string returned because it's storage may be reused.